# x86 assembly "push OFFSET ..." and mnemonics?

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2012, disassembly

I'm trying to teach myself a bit of assembly by creating small C programs in **Visual Studio 2012 Express**, and then disassembling them in **Immunity Debugger**. But I've obviously run into something I do not understand:

```
012A13F0   68 58582A01      PUSH OFFSET Hello_Wo.??_C@_0M@KPLPPDAC@H>; ASCII "Hello World"
012A13F5   FF15 BC922A01    CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&MSVCR110D.printf>]  ; MSVCR110.printf
```

I'm confused by both of these instructions. In fact, the opcodes make more sense to me than the actual instructions depicted by the debugger.

Obviously, the first instruction pushes an address onto the stack. When I follow the address in the dump, it shows me an area which contains some hexadecimals that comprise the string `Hello World`. I believe this is the `.data segment`. Am I correct?

And also; I guess `Hello_Wo.??_C@_0M@...`  is just a visual aid provided to me by the debugger, so I could better understand that this is... Something...

But what does the **OFFSET** mean in this push instruction? I haven't been able to find anything on Google on it.

I would also like to ask about the other instruction...

As far as I understand, it is trying to call a routine by using the 4-byte value located at the address `DS:[102A92BC] (&MSVCR110D...)`, *as the address of the call*?

The debugger tells me that `DS:[102A92BC] = 5C0A93A0`. And that memory range is reserved for MSVCR110's `.text segment`.

I'm very sorry, but I had a hard time making this question, as I wasn't even really sure how I should ask it. I hope you understand. And thank you.

**Off-topic:** I have one last question that is a bit stupid, and off-topic, but I hope you don't mind: You aren't suppose to read data segments as disassembled code, ever, are you? the imports data segment made me confused in my search for `5C0A93A0`.

Comment: I don't want to add an answer, since I'm not sure if I'm entirely right, but I'll give it a shot, hopefully it will get us started ;D 1) Not sure what's with the _C@_M@..., but all OFFSET is saying is that rather than being an expression, it's a raw offset (might also have some thing to do with the base address, I'll have a further look later) 2. The reason print is in the .text segment is because it is an import. This refers to the jump table for MsVcr110.DLL. Your program can't know the exact address or print ahead of time, so it is put here when the program is run, and you call it instead.

Comment: 3. You CAN read code from .text, but in most (if not all cases), it won't make sense to do so. It's just what the disassembler makes of the data there, usually its just data and the disassembler throws up garbage. There may be some edge cases where some code is run from .text, but for security reasons, I believe it's mapped into non-executable memory. Again, I'll have another look, I'm no pro here, just trying to help.

Comment: So what base address does push "offset" in this regard?

Comment: I'm not too sure about the OFFSET syntax here, so I'd take @johnfound's word over mine. By base address, I meant the address where the section is loaded. Each section of the executable is mapped into virtual memory, this includes the program code. If you want to say, jump to a function, you have to jump to the location of the function IN MEMORY. So, say we have a function at .text+0x123456, and .text is loaded at 0x40000000(== base address), then the instruction would be `jmp 0x40123456`, but the disassembler takes away this base address to make things easier to read.

Comment: Tbh, if you look at the opcode "68 58582A01" it doesn't even look like 'OFFSET' is taken into account for anything. According to (http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html) '68' is just the opcode for a simple push.

Comment: It makes me think that this is the something the debugger is coming up with. I think what @johnfound is talking about is how it is used together with segments. But he also says that modern OSs use a flat memory model, which makes it even more strange... Since there's no segments to really offset, except for what you're saying. (the base address)

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.hitxp.com/comp/pro/asm/120403.htm, seems like it should help clear some stuff up for you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In x86 architecture, every address has two parts - segment and offset. So, OFFSET means simply that the offset of the address of some variable "Hello_Wo.??_C@_0M@KPLPPDAC@H" is pushed in the stack. This directive is from the MASM syntax where "push variable" means push the value of the variable and "push offset variable" means push the offset of the variable.

Mentioned ".data" and ".text" are not segments, but sections. It's completely different. The section is just a part of the executable file that has separate memory protection. The C/C++ compilers usually use ".text" for the program code. Don't ask me why.

In the modern protected mode OSes, flat memory model is used. That means all code and data is placed in one big segment, so you never has to work with DS, ES, etc. segment registers. Their values are managed by the OS.

P.S. Beginning to learn assembly language with reversing HLL programs is not the best strategy.

Better try to read and write some native assembly code. There are many places in Internet where you can download such examples - very simple and very complex, depending on your progress. I would suggest using [FASM](http://flatassembler.net). There is a message board, with tons of useful information and people that can answer your questions.

Comment: Besides learning assembly, I would like to learn to read the disassembly produced by Windows. Would learning FASM/NASM help me there? Or should I learn assembly while also disassembling HLL programs?

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by Offset? Do you mean pointer dereferencing? Since he followed the pushed location in the dump and it lead to "Hello World", and "Hello World" cannot be in the stack (where the variable is), I don't understand what you mean by `the offset of the address of some variable[i.e the location of a variable] is pushed in the stack`?

Comment: @AStupidNoob I don't know actually what "pointer dereferencing" means. Every variable has some address. In x86 architecture, the address consists of two numbers - segment and offset. The offset is simply, offset from the beginning of the segment. In the flat memory model (Windows, Linux, etc.) all the memory accessible by the program is placed in one single segment, so the program works only with the offsets of the memory locations. In this case, you can assume "offset" is the same as "address".

Comment: All I meant by pointer dereferencing was just getting the value at that location, i.e. if `apples` is 0x40123456 and there is the value `255` at address `0x40123456`, then dereferencing `apples` yields `255`, because apples is a pointer to `255`. AFAIK, there aren't two SEPERATE numbers for segment and offset: In the executable maybe, but in memory, the segment base is added to the offset to produce just one address. So how does `PUSH OFFSET somevariablehere` come to pushing the offset of "Hello World" in .data if the address of `somevariablehere` is on the stack

Comment: @Volatile For reading disassembly produced by Windows check out "Matt's Just Enough Assembly Language to Get By" two part guide written back in 1998 for MSJ. Part 1 at http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0298/hood0298.aspx and part 2 at http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0698/hood0698.aspx